Как правильно возвращать данные с сервера, если пользователь их еще не создал? (Express / Node.js)
Всем привет!
Я пишу небольшое TODO на Express.js, TS, Knex.js
Скорее это вопрос больше философский, но мне интересно было бы узнать мнение и Ваши подходы с учетом опыта.
Допустим, авторизованный пользователь хочет получить информацию из БД по каким либо сущностям (например, задачи / тэги и т.д.), но он еще НЕ создавал ни одной сущности;
Как правильно отвечать на такие запросы?

Где-то есть практика возврата пустого массива [] со статусом
200;

Где-то описание ошибки и статус 404, если сущность не найдена;


Какой подход Вы считаете наиболее правильным?

Вы для начала определитесь - сущность или сущности, это ж разные вещи и разные запросы

В таком случае хотел бы узнать практику как для одной сущности, так и для нескольких

Одна сущность - статус 4XX, ошибка. Несколько сущностей - статус 200, пустой массив.
